# Origin of the phrase “close to the bone”

Tags: etymology

I need to find out the earliest use of the phrase, “close to the bone”. [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=close%20to%20bone) and other [online dictionaries](https://www.google.com/search?q=close%20to%20the%20bone%20origin&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&oq=close%20to%20the%20bone%20origin&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l2.7241j0j0&hl=it&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) don’t give details about its earliest usage.

Comment: Hello, Beth. After you have shown some signs of research (the phrase is not that hard to find in dictionaries etc), if you still have difficulties, that would be the right time for a contributor here to offer help. ELU needs to hold true to its mission statement.

Comment: I don't know about *origin*, but the figurative usage (said of a potentially "wounding" *remark*) only seems to have gained traction since WW2. And per [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bit+close+to+the+bone%2Cbit+near+to+the+bone%2Cbit+near+to+the+bone%2Cbit+near+the+bone&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbit%20close%20to%20the%20bone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbit%20near%20the%20bone%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cbit%20close%20to%20the%20bone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbit%20near%20the%20bone%3B%2Cc0)...

Comment: ...the ***British English*** version that I grew up with is usually *[That's a bit] **near the bone***, but this is now getting swamped by AmE ***...close to** the bone*.

Comment: Yes; the phrase may be easy to find, but its etymology isn't. [The Phrase Finder](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/near-the-knuckle.html) only lists the related 'near the knuckle', as used by the variety hall producer / artiste Nellie L'Estrange for a mooted play ('A Bit Too Near the Knuckle') in 1887.

Comment: Could it be related to _'My bone cleaveth to my skin and to my flesh, and I am escaped with the skin of my teeth'_? The last part is an expression, and it sounds similar to the first part.

Comment: Without having done any research into the question, it seems to me that two hypothetical interpretations are plausible: (1) "close to the bone" means "deeply or—more particularly—dangerously deeply," on the analogy of a stab wound; (2) "close to the bone" means "efficiently or with minimal waste," on the analogy of carving meat from, say, a turkey. It would be interesting to know whether both meanings have been intended at various times and, if so, which one came first.

Comment: @user067531 Yes, I agree that the question is fundamentally valid and useful. But it's not the non-researcher who should be getting the upvotes, but you.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - brand new users should be supported, I think. Just closing the question would be of no help to anyone.

Comment: @user067531 The trouble is that so many new users don't bother to look at site requirements, never mind make any attempt to observe them. Worse, some that do read them challenge the requirements. I'm not sure whether 'ELU is different in some respects from other SE sites' is still in play, but the mission statement _was_ to provide a searchable English language repository for reference, not be all things to all people. / I redressed what I thought was the unwarranted +2, but held off close-voting till now. If someone resubmits with reasonable research (even what avenues failed), fine.

Comment: A German variant uses *marrow* and describes, in my experience, fear. On the other hand, *bone* is cognate to German *Bein* "bone, leg"; in that sense, could *close to the bone* mean *bellow the waste line*; you know, *the bone*? ;-)

Comment: A similar phrase is considered in this Q. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/404447/etymology-of-bare-bones-barebones . I suspect the modern turn of phrase is a mashup of earlier phrases going back to antiquity.

Comment: Tried searching Ngram, but many references come up that use the term literally, in medical contexts and in cooking, so it would be hard to sort out the first metaphorical uses.  Incidentally, the first uses appear to be in describing surgeries, ca 1725.

Answer (score 1):

Instances of "close to the bone" in a literal sense go back at least as far as 1708. From the entry on "Bones" in John Harris, [*Lexicon Technicum: or An Universal English Dictionary of Arts and Sciences*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=osu.32435067908665&view=1up&seq=123&size=150), second edition, volume 1 (1708):

> The inner Superficies of the *Periosteum* sticks as **close to the Bone** as if it were glued to it ; and besides, the *Periosteum* has little *Fibrillæ* or Threads continued from it, that enter into the Substance of the Bone, which gives them (probably) some internal Sense.

And similarly, from Nathan Bailey, [*Dictionarium Rusticum, Urbanicum & Botanicum: or A Dictionary of Husbandry, Gardening, Trade, Commerce, and All Sorts of Country-Affairs*](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=nnc1.cu04867629&view=1up&seq=258), third edition, volume 1 (1726):

> **EXCRETION-BONEY** ; an evil incident to Horses, occasion'd mostly by Causticks, or burning Corrosives, unduely put to Wounds that lie **close to the Bone**, as when the Wound is in the Leg, or about the Pasterns; for the Flesh being much burned by them, causes an Excrescence to grow upon the Bone, which by the little Experience of the Farrier is healed, but the Excretion remains; and sometimes it comes by a Shackle, or the galling of a Lock, or Fetters that have been long continued upon the Foot. What is proper for the Bone-Spavin, likewise cures this.

Figurative or poetic use "close to the bone" appears at least as early as Henry David Thoreau's poem "[The Old Marlborough Road](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uva.x000421995&view=1up&seq=43)" (1850), reprinted in *Collected Poems of Henry Thoreau* (1943):

> O man of wild habits, / Partridges and rabbits, / Who hast no cares / Only to set snares, / Who liv'st all alone, / **Close to the bone**, / And where life is sweetest / Constantly eatest.

From Oliver Wendell Holmes , "[My Search for 'The Captain'](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=gri.ark:/13960/t9q288146&view=1up&seq=110)" (1863), in *Soundings from the Atlantic* (1864):

> A feeble, attenuated old man, who wore the Rebel uniform, if such it could be called, stood by without showing any sign of intelligence. It was cutting very **close to the bone** to carve such a shred of humanity from the body politic to make a soldier of.

And from Charles Van Zandt, "[Commemorative Address Spoken Before the Rhode Island Society for the Encouragement of Domestic Industry](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.32044086386349&view=1up&seq=5)" (January 19, 1870):

> If you doubt this [the need for industry, intelligence, and morality in defense of Rhode Island's interest"] to-day, it will be irresistibly forced home upon you to-morrow, and you will learn how very **close to the bone** the unconscious tooth of humanity is always gnawing.

---

It is interesting that all three of the earliest examples of figurative use of "close to the bone" that I found are from New England sources. However, the number of instances is so small that it is impossible to draw any firm conclusion about the probable geographic origin of the phrase from those examples.

Answer (score 0):

The origin of the phrase appears to be Old English:  [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/21294?redirectedFrom=near%20the%20bone#eid1259345200)

**to the bone** or **to the bare bone**

Phrases

> - (a) to the bone (also to the bare bone).
> - (i) Right through the flesh so as to reach the bone. Frequently    hyperbolical, or in figurative contexts.

Old English usage:(prior to ~ 1300)

> OE   Ælfric Let. to Sigeweard (De Veteri et Novo Test.) (Laud) 61   On
>   weallendum ele he het hine baðian, for ðan þe se hata ele gæð in **to
>   ðam bane**.

And a more modern figurative uasge:

> Swindells Follow Shadow (1991)   I was walking head bowed and half
>   blind in the teeth of a wind which keened like a mourner and cut me **to
>   the bone.**

Comment: Actually “to the bone” https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to%20the%20bone appears to have a different  connotation from that of  “close/near to the bone” https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/close+to+the+bone

Comment: Are there any examples given which include 'near' or 'close'? I won't ask about ðam banes, ðam banes, ðam ....

Comment: none in this citation

Answer (score 0):

The phrase, in its current adjectival sense, seems relatively recent and of Scottish origins and found its way quickly into Modern English.

From the OED:

It seems to have started with

> **k. near (also close to) the bone.**
>
> **(a) Scottish. Of a person or his or her behaviour: parsimonious; miserly, stingy.**
>
> 1866   W. Gregor Dial. Banffshire (Philol. Soc.) 117   *He's unco near the bane, wi' a' thing it he gees.* [= He is remarkably near the bone, with anything that he gives]
>
> 1985   Conc. Sc. Dict. 436/1   Near the bane *[=bone]*, miserly.

The idea of miserliness seems to have been associated with being thin because of a lack of nourishment – so miserly that a person would almost starve himself. It was then extended to include ‘having little or nothing’ and thus being dangerously close to disaster because of a lack of resources:

> **(b) Close to the minimum level or standard possible; esp. close to the limit of survival or subsistence; frequently in to live close to (also near) the bone: to live frugally or in poverty; to manage on the barest minimum**.
>
> 1873   Milwaukee (Wisconsin) Sunday Sentinel 6 Apr. 6/2   *He has had a hard time and has lived close to the bone.*
>
> 2001   Technol. Rev. Dec. 87/2   *Undoubtedly, many companies, running close to the bone, couldn't afford to safely clone their archives in more than one place.*

In its turn, the meaning was extended again to encompass the meaning being generally in a dangerous position because of one’s own behaviour.

> **(c) Close to an established limit with regard to behaviour or politeness; verging on indecency or offensiveness; (also) uncomfortably close to the truth. Cf. near the knuckle at knuckle n. 2b.**
>
> 1929   Smith's Weekly (Sydney) 29 June 14   *Getting rather near the bone. After all, there are some things you simply can't make jokes about.*
>
> 1980   Canberra Times 3 May 13/6   *It is an utterly gripping story, but..too close to the bone, and too lacking in light relief.*
>
> 2013   Daily Tel. 11 June 20/4   *The self-mocking has to be close to the bone, it has to hurt, or it doesn't work.*